# Assigning RegExp.test to a variable

Tags: javascript, regex, functional-programming

The following code:

```
var r = /^[0-9A-Z]$/.test;
r("A")
```

Throws 'TypeError: can't convert undefined to object'

How else could I assign the test function to a variable, for passing in functions, later evaluation, etc.? (Without wrapping the regex in another function)

Update:

Consider this bit of valid code before answering:

```
var o = { f: function() { return 1 } };
var a = o.f;
var b = a();     // b = 1
```

Comment: I doubt this is what you intend, but `var r = /^[0-9A-Z]$/.test;` is assigning the regex method named "test" to r.  It's not assigning the regular expression to r which is why the next line of code doesn't work.

Comment: @jfriend00: I'm pretty sure that is what he is after, he's just missing the `apply` or `call` part.

Comment: @mu is too short - I rather doubt that because he used `r.test("A")`.  That doesn't work for a bunch of reasons.  First r is just a method - it has lost it's association with the regex.  Second, test("A") would be like doing RexExp.prototype.test.test("A").  So something is really amiss.

Comment: @jfriend00 You spotted a typo. Thanks for that.

Comment: @jfriend00 - What do you mean by 'lost its association with the regex'?

Comment: The way you have r assigned now, it's just a method.  It has no association with your regular expression object at all.  To use it, you would have to use apply() or call() and pass in the appropriate object to use with the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has to do with the value of `this` inside the `test` method.

For example:

```
var obj = {
  method: function () { return this === obj }
};

obj.method(); // true

var method = obj.method;
method(); // false
```

If you call the `test` method "as a function" -as your example `r();`-, the `this` value will refer to `undefined` (for built-in or strict functions in ECMAScript 5, in the above example `this` will refer to the global object).

Calling any method of `RegExp.prototype` with a `this` value that is not a `RegExp` object, will always generate this `TypeError` exception, quoting the spec:

[15.10.6 Properties of the RegExp Prototype Object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.10.6)

> In the following descriptions of functions that are properties of the RegExp prototype object, the phrase “this RegExp object” refers to the object that is the this value for the invocation of the function; a TypeError exception is thrown if the this value is not an object or an object for which the value of the [[Class]] internal property is not "RegExp".

However you could bind the `test` method to your `r` function, using the `Function.prototype.bind` method:

```
var re = /^[0-9A-Z]$/,
    r = re.test.bind(re);

r("A"); // true
```

Or using `call` or `apply`:

```
var r = re.test;
r.call(re, "A"); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

As I've been essentially trying to answer this question in all my comments, let's summarize everything we've covered so far in an actual answer.

When you do this:

```
var r = /^[0-9A-Z]$/.test;
```

you are assigning the method named `test` from the `RegExp` object to the variable named `r`.  It is just a method assignment.  There is no connection whatsoever with the specific regular expression object that you created.  If fact, `r == RegExp.prototype.test`.

When you then try this line of code:

```
r("A")
```

you are trying to execute `RegExp.prototype.test` and passing it `"A"`, but you have no appropriate object context.  When the test function runs, the `this` pointer won't point to a regular expression object, it will point to the global object (which in a browser is the `window` object).

In your o, a and b code example, it works because all you're doing is calling functions that refer to no instance data and the this pointer is not used at all (therefore it doesn't matter that it's not set to an appropriate object context).  That isn't the case with the regular expression method.  It needs its instance data (e.g. it's `this` pointer to point to a real regular expression object).

It is possible to take a method point and add the appropriate `this` pointer, though I have no idea why that would be useful in this particular example.  For example, you could do this:

```
var re = /^[0-9A-Z]$/;
var r = re.test;
r.call(re);
```

That sets the `this` pointer to your regular expression object and then executes the `r` method with that `this` pointer.

I don't really know why you'd want to do that, but hopefully that helps explain things.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. True to your reasoning, the following works: r.foo = r.test; r.foo("A")

Answer (score 0):

MAJOR EDIT: Now that I've seen your update, which removed the problem my original post talked about, I realise that the problem is the `test` function needs to be associated to an object when it runs. Standard dot notation after a regex object will automatically set `this` within `test` equal to that object. When you call it by itself as `r("A");` then `this` will be set to the window object, which doesn't work and gives an error. (This wouldn't matter for some functions, but `test` needs its `this` object to be a regex to operate on.)

You can make it work by explicitly setting the `this` using `.call()`:

```
var re = /^[0-9A-Z]$/;
var rf = re.test;

alert(rf.call(re,"A"));     // displays 'true'
alert(rf.call(/blah/,"A")); // displays 'false'
```

But that seems pretty silly. I'd ask why you can't just do this:

```
var r = /^[0-9A-Z]$/;
r.test("A");
r.test("B");
```

This lets you keep one copy of the regex, and you don't need your own function wrapper. If you really want the `r("A")` syntax just add a wrapper.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. It was a typo. But the code fails all the same. Perhaps it has something to do with the internal workings of the RegExp object?

Comment: Also, your suggested alternative misses the point. I'm not trying to evaluate some regex, I want to bind the test function to a variable.

Comment: When you do `var r = /^[0-9A-Z]$/.test;`, you are assigning the method `test` to r.  It's just a method == RegExp.prototype.test and it's implemented in native code which is why you get the alert(r) you do.  There is no object association at all in r - just a pointer to a method.

Comment: My apologies that your comments no longer make sense in relation to my answer: obviously I've revised it substantially. After seeing the updated question I suddenly realised what the problem was and went off to try it for myself before posting a (I hope) final version of my answer. Of course, by the time I then finished my update there were other answers that explained the same thing. Oh well.