# Why does this JavaScript code with a regex not work as I expected?

Tags: javascript, overriding

```
a = /\d+/.exec; 
a("hello,123")
```

I getting the following error:

```
Error: can't convert undefined to object
```

Why is `a` returned as undefined?

Comment: See for more details: [Assigning RegExp.test to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951266/assigning-regexp-test-to-a-variable/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` in this case is a reference to the `RegExp.prototype.exec` function itself, and is not actually bound to any regular expression.  Either of these would work:

```
var a = /\d+/.exec('hello,123');
```

---

```
var rx = /\d+/,
     a = rx.exec;

a.call(rx, 'hello,123');
```

Your `undefined` is coming from an internal reference to `this` from within the `exec` function.